# Is it possible to exclude default incoming call and provide same call in my running application

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-permissions

I have a special situation in which i have to exclude an incoming call .Means it should notify user about call at phone level .It should redirect user to my application and in my app user can see that someone is calling there .Even user can only get ringing tone when he gets redirected to my application .Well i know that these features do not give user comfort anyhow .But still i want some guidance on how to make this.

I thank all in advance who try to get this question and provide their time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BroadcastReceiver as follows :

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<receiver android:name=".broadReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

By this you will receive phone call information before the phone rings.Now in your BroadcastReceiver just get all the information you want and show in your app and than call

```
abortBroadcast();
```

This will disconnect the call.So assign it appropriately.